# html: classes using external css

Tags: html

I am new to html and css and am stuck on classes using external css style.. Please guide me. this is my html code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
 <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<h1 class="ha">Welcome!!!</h1>

<hr>

<p class="style">welcome to our website!!!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my external css code:

```
h1.ha{color:blue;font-size:450%;text-allign:center;}
p.style{color:red;font-size:250%;}
```

Comment: When you go to get a haircut and they ask how you want it do you say "I just want my hair cut"?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the problem? You must be more specific...

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Is it not working at all? or just some part?

Comment: `text-allign` should be `text-align` (one l).

Comment: For future reference, as Vinc said, it's not clear what's going wrong; also, just so you know, many, many very basic flukes can be found by opening your browsers' Developer Tools (usually F12, or right-clicking an element and clicking Inspect Element)

Comment: Sorry but i actually am new to html and ma age is only 14. I have programmed in VB.net and C++ but em new to web development. Can you please tell me what's wrong with ma code cox color and font size is not actually changing?

Comment: Have you checked to see that the path to your CSS file is correct?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Yeah both are in the same folder Vucko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When linking to an external CSS use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>    <!-- You have "ref" instead of "rel" -->
```

Then in your `styles.css` file:

```
.ha {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 45px;    /* I recommend using px, or em/rem for sizing text (ex: 12px) */
    text-align: center; /* You had a typo */
}

.style {
    color: red;
    font-size: 25px;    /* Again, use px, em or rem for text sizing */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vucko - probably should have used correct commenting in my examples above.

Comment: Happy to help.  SO is a great resource for developers and it is always the first place I go when I hit a problem. Best of luck to you in future development!  Don't forget to mark this answer as your solution.

Comment: It was a silly mistake done by me but to your surprise I've just started programming on html today. I've programmed in VB.net, C++ and C programming languages previously and yeah I was good in that.......

Comment: Haha understandable - I've been developing for the web / web apps for quite a few years now and more than I'd like to admit make stupid mistakes that leave me baffled.  (Often a missing .  or , )

Comment: Anyway, once again thanks fa helping

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code. Corrects are `rel="stylesheet"` and `text-align:center`

Comment: Offtopic, but I'm 14 years old too :)

Comment: Dear, I said em new to web development and to your surprise I have started it today. I've programmed in VB.net, C++ and C programming languages previously and yeah I was good in that..... TuomasK